# Bootstrap add-on on buttons

Tags: html

[image]

I am an bit new to Bootstrap but I can't ind it anywhere on the manual how to give the add on in the last line (where the txt is 'cm') the dimensions as the previous 3 lines.

```
<!-- width right -->
<div id="div_widthRight" class="form-group has-warning">
<label for="widthRight" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Breedte rechts</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="widthRight" name="width_right" min="20" max="252" value="" data-preview="preview_hl_right" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()">
    <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- height -->
<div id="div_height" class="form-group has-warning">
<label for="height" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hoogte</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_1" name="height" value="1" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onclick="validate_but(this);validate()">14,5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_2" name="height" value="2" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onclick="validate_but(this);validate()">29,0</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_3" name="height" value="3" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onclick="validate_but(this);validate()">43,5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_4" name="height" value="4" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onclick="validate_but(this);validate()">58,0</button>
    <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Or is it because  I am using different classes? But to get this aligned correct?

This is what I am trying to get.
[image]

When adding the input-group class to btn-group.
Width 0 on the input-group-addon. I have this result:[image]

When only adding Width 0 on the input-group-addon.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited my answer since my first answer did not work properly in all resolutions. I think this is one way to achieve what you want. I have changed some of your bootstrap classes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="div_height" class="form-group has-warning">
    <label for="height" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hoogte</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_1" name="height" value="1" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onclick="validate_but(this);validate()">14,5</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_2" name="height" value="2" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onclick="validate_but(this);validate()">29,0</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_3" name="height" value="3" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onclick="validate_but(this);validate()">43,5</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_4" name="height" value="4" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onclick="validate_but(this);validate()">58,0</button>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeppsen. See my edits in my post of the results.

Comment: @Muiter. I have edited my answer. Maybe this will work for you.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your effort @Jeppsen